Can you replace a failed drive during a rebuild to the hot-spare
I have a Dell PowerEdge T630 with a PERC H730.  There are 3 disks in a RAID5 configuration and fourth disk as a hot-spare.  It looks like this :-

Disk0 - 4Tb Disk (in the RAID)
Disk1 - 4Tb Disk (in the RAID)
Disk2 - 4Tb Disk (in the RAID)
Disk3 - 4Tb Disk hot-spare

Just over 10 hours ago Disk1 failed and the PERC controller correctly put DISK3 online and started the rebuild.  So it now looks like this :-

Disk0 - 4Tb Disk (online)
Disk1 - 4Tb Disk (BAD)
Disk2 - 4Tb Disk (online)
Disk3 - 4Tb Disk (rebuild)

So my question is this for those DELL PERC experts.

Is it safe to pull DISK1 out and replace it with a new disk whilst the RAID is rebuilding?

If yes, can I then make that new DISK1 a hot-spare whilst the RAID is rebuilding?


I'm just worried that if one disk has gone that another could follow it (Hopefully whilst the RAID isn't rebuilding)

Not exactly sure about an H730, but PERCs usually start a copy back to the replaced drive, freeing the hot spare once more.

@Zac67 in that case, probably best to wait for the disk rebuild to complete, before replacing the failed disk

The original question was, Can you replace a failed drive during a rebuild to the hot-spare
The short answer is NO.
Here's happens
The Dell PowerEdge T630 with a PERC H730. There are 3 disks in a RAID5 configuration and fourth disk as a hot-spare. It looks like this :-

Disk0 - 4Tb Disk (in the RAID)
Disk1 - 4Tb Disk (in the RAID)
Disk2 - 4Tb Disk (in the RAID)
Disk3 - 4Tb Disk hot-spare

Disk1 failed and the PERC controller correctly put DISK3 online and started the rebuild. So it now looks like this :-

Disk0 - 4Tb Disk (online)
Disk1 - 4Tb Disk (BAD)
Disk2 - 4Tb Disk (online)
Disk3 - 4Tb Disk (rebuild)

Wait for the rebuild to complete and it looks like this :-

Disk0 - 4Tb Disk (online)
Disk1 - 4Tb Disk (BAD)
Disk2 - 4Tb Disk (online)
Disk3 - 4Tb Disk (online)

Now replace Disk1 and boot up.  The PERC automatically see a disk replacement and initiates a CopyBack process, and that looks like this :-

Disk0 - 4Tb Disk (online)
Disk1 - 4Tb Disk (CopyBack)
Disk2 - 4Tb Disk (online)
Disk3 - 4Tb Disk (online)

Basically the data on the hot-spare is copied back to the new disk and then the hot-spare is returned to its hot-spare status, like this :-

Disk0 - 4Tb Disk (online)
Disk1 - 4Tb Disk (online)
Disk2 - 4Tb Disk (online)
Disk3 - 4Tb Disk hot-spare

I didn't once have to do a CTRL+R in the PERC management, or use the iDRAC.  The rebuild and replace progress was really straight forward.
If you're wondering on timescales.  The PERC was set to a rebuild priority of 30% and took approx 13-14 hours for each rebuild.
